# Integrating passport middleware in swagger nodejs restful app?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, passport.js

Recently started exploring swagger for nodejs express app.
As far as I understood, swagger is kind of framework which requires conventions to follow in nodejs express app. Swagger maps routes automatically with controllers.

But I feel, i loose the capability to inject middlewares like passport for authentication, which can easily be added in user-defined routes.

I know there are ways to inject middlewares with swagger, but somehow I feel it's not as natural as it's without swagger.

Is there a way I can use swagger with minimal swagger related components in my code - probably with just swagger.yaml file only ?

I want to avoid req.swagger.param kind of code and want to leverage standard way to defining routes and injecting middleware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swagger itself is a middleware. When you start your application, swagger will register itself using app.Use([swaggerMiddlewareObject]). So you can add other middlwares before/after swagger.

Please find the commented section below. You would have to change it based on your authentication strategy.

```
'use strict';

var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = app; // for testing

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname // required config
};

/*Mount your passport Middleware here using app object. As your are building a stateless restful api, I assume you would use jwt
* 1. import jwt-strategy.
* 2. Configure passport to use jwt strategy.
* 3. app.use(passport.initialize());
* 4. app.use('/pathYouWantProtect', passport.authenticate('jwt-strategy'),function(req,res,next){
*       
*    });
*/

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);

  var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;
  app.listen(port);

  if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/hello']) {
    console.log('try this:\ncurl http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/hello?name=Scott');
  }
});
```

Comment: I had to remove the function() callback to make it work otherwise it was overwriting the other route for the path:

`app.get("/api/v1/users", passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }));`

Answer (score 0):

My solution. Need to define a middleware

```
  ./middleware/passport

  export.swaggerPassport = function(passport) {
    const applyPassport = passportService(passport);
    return function(controller) {
       const action = async (req, res, next) => {
          const [err, user] = await applyPassport(req, res, next);
          if (err) {
            return errorResponse(res, err, 422);
          }
          controller.action(req, res, next);
       };
       return { spec: controller.spec, action };
     }
  };

 ../services/util.service

exports.swaggerPassport = function(passport) {
  const applyPassport = passportService(passport);
  return function(controller) {
    const action = async (req, res, next) => {
      const [err, user] = await applyPassport(req, res, next);
        if (err) {
          return errorResponse(res, err, 422);
        }
        controller.action(req, res, next);
    };
    return { spec: controller.spec, action };
  }
};
```

then pass there a passport

```
server.js

const { passportStrategy, swaggerPassport } = require('./middleware/passport');
passportStrategy(passport);
const routePassport = swaggerPassport(passport);
```

and call when we need to protect a controller action

```
swagger.addGet(routePassport(api.Dashboard.dashboard))
```

all code available in [github](https://github.com/navikom/restApi)